# Finding $x^4 + y^4 + z^4$ using geometric series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

This is a problem from the [2001 Stanford Math Tournament Algebra section](http://sumo.stanford.edu/smt/2001/smt-questions.pdf). 
$$$$Given that $$x+y+z=3$$ $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5$$$$x^3+y^3+z^3=7$$Find $x^4+y^4+z^4$. $$$$My friend claimed that he was able to solve this question using geometric series, i.e. adding the above three equations together and forming geometric series with three terms, but I can't see how he solved it using that method. I solved it using the method described in the [solutions document](http://sumo.stanford.edu/smt/2001/smt-solutions.pdf), but I haven't seen a solution using geometric series. Can anyone find a way to solve the problem using geometric series? Any help with this problem would be great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: is your friend prone to lying?

Comment: Maybe he used some other method, but didn't want you to win, so he gave you a false hint to lead you in the wrong direction.

Comment: Since the *only* possible answer is $\frac 16 a^4 - b a^2 + \frac 43 ac + \frac 12 b^2$ with $a=x+y+z$, $b=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $c=x^3+y^3+z^3$, there is little room for alternative theories. maybe he used not a geometric series, but an arithmetic sequence to qǵuess the next value? In that case he was lucky ...

Comment: Good thing these aren't integer solutions. *cough* fermat *cough*

Comment: You should ask him to substantiate his claim. For example, it is not true that "the sum must follow an arithmetic progression". As a side note, $x^0 + y^0 + z^0 = 3 $.

Comment: Does this generalize to $x^n+y^n+z^n=2n+1$ for $n \geq 1$?

Comment: @DanielR Notice that the values of $x+y+z$, $x^2+y^2+z^2$, and $x^3+y^3+z^3$ determine those of $x,y,z$. The system of equations you propose for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ doesn't have solutions.

Comment: @RGB: Sure, what I meant was if the solutions of the equations in the OP give $2n+1$ when plugged into the expression $x^n+y^n+z^n$ (since the answer for $n=4$ is $9$). They don't, I checked it myself. For $n=5$ the result seems to be $\frac{29}{3}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a rather encumbered solution for a not-as-hard problem, and it is the only way I see to make sense of what your friend is saying. On the other hand, it is cool that it let us know about Newton's identities and their [proof using generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Comparing_coefficients_in_series).

Let us form the formal series \begin{align}F(x,y,z,t)&:=(x+y+z)t+(z^2+y^2+z^2)t^2+(x^3+y^3+z^3)t^3+\ldots\\&=3t+5t^2+7t^3+at^4+\ldots,\end{align}
where $a:=x^4+y^4+z^4$ is the number we want to find.

Forming this power series is *kind of* adding the given equations (as your friend suggested), but we multiply them first by $t,t^2,t^3,...$, respectively, before adding.

Consider the polynomial \begin{align}G(x,y,z,t)&:=-1+(x+y+z)t+(xy+xz+yz)t^2-(xyz)t^3\\&=-1+3t+(xy+xz+yz)t^2-(xyz)t^3\end{align}

We multiply $F$ times $G$. It happens that we get a polynomial:

\begin{align}
FG&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(xt)^k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(yt)^k+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(zt)^k\right)G\\
&=-\left(\frac{xt}{1-xt}+\frac{yt}{1-yt}+\frac{yt}{1-xt}\right)(1-xt)(1-yt)(1-zt)\\
&=t\left((-x)(1-yt)(1-zt)+(-y)(1-xt)(1-zt)+(-z)(1-xt)(1-yt)\right)\\
&=-(x+y+z)t+(xy+xz+yz)t^2-(xyz)t^3\\
&=-3t+(xy+xz+yz)t^2-(xyz)t^3
\end{align}

In the second equality we used the sum of the geometric series *more or less* like your friend said.

Comparing coefficients of the multiplication $FG$ with the result in the last line we get (the Newton's identities for the values in this problem)

\begin{align}
2(xy+xz+yz)&=9-5\\
3xyz&=3(xy+xz+yz)-15+7\\
0&=3(xyz)-5(xy+xz+yz)+21-(x^4+y^4+z^4)
\end{align}

From these, substituting from top to bottom, we find the value of $x^4+y^4+z^4$. Notice that the method allows us to continue using the equalities between coefficients of higher degree in $t$ to compute $x^5+y^5+z^5$, $x^6+y^6+z^6$, and so on ...