# A painful system of symmetric equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I came across this problem from a post on instagram.
$$x^4+y^4+z^4=32$$
$$x^5+y^5+z^5=186$$
$$x^6+y^6+z^6=803$$
$$(x+y+z) \;\;\; \epsilon \;\;\; N$$
$$x+y+z=?$$

**My attempt**: I set the following: $$x+y+z=a$$ $$xy+yz+za=b$$
$$xyz=c$$ $$$$Now I tried to express each equations in terms of $a,b,c$ and hence solve for but I end up with a huge mess and nothing works out. There are just too many terms in the expansion of $\;\; (x+y+z)^6$. There must be a better way out of this.

Comment: Yes, this has been solved here at this site (Newton identities). See the answer, for example, by Nikos to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556726/how-to-find-x4y4z4-from-equation).

Comment: More duplicates are [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325068/if-abc-4-a2b2c2-7-a3b3c3-28-find-a4b4c4-and-a5b5c?noredirect=1), [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360541/what-is-alpha4-beta4-gamma4?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891979/solving-complex-number-equation-with-galois-theory?noredirect=1).

Comment: In case you wonder about the result: It is, for example, $x+y+z=6$, with $x=3$ and $y^2-3y+5=0$.

Comment: I had a look at the solution by Nikos to a similar problem. It looks complicated to me but I'll make work of it. Thanks!!

Comment: It may look complicated at first sight, but after you understood the principle, it is easy. Anyway, since you said "*but I end up with a huge mess and nothing works out*", you have no alternative.